Realize friend on sqlalchemy
I have table User and i need make relationsgip between two objects user
i make table Follow but it doesn't work
class Follow(SqlAlchemyBase):
    __tablename__ = 'followers'

    followid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    follower = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    followeruser = orm.relationship("User")
    followed = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, sqlalchemy.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    followeduser = orm.relationship("User")

my user model:
class User(SqlAlchemyBase, UserMixin, SerializerMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    followers = orm.relationship("Follow", back_populates='followeruser')
    age = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, nullable=True)
    about = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True, default='Не важно')
    email = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, index=True, unique=True, nullable=True)
    avatar = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, default='images/default/avatar.jpg')
    hashed_password = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, nullable=True)
    modified_date = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)
    is_private = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String, default='False')
    quezes = orm.relationship("Quezes", back_populates='author')


Please explain "doesn't work".

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622922/how-to-implement-following-followers-relationship-in-sqlalchemy

sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.followers - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables via secondary table 'follow'.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference from the secondary table to each of the parent and child tables.
